# Android automatic webview login

Tags: android, authentication, android-webview

I am trying to get my webview to show a page that is only accesible after i am logged in. but whatever i try i cant get past the login url.
How can i open/show the SEND_VISUM_URL after i login.
this is what i have so far:

```
 String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.35.50.125/BCS/index.php?module=";
 String SEND_VISUM_URL = "http://10.35.50.1/BCS/index.php?module=ScanVisa&Action=save";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
        webView.loadUrl(LOGIN_URL);

        cookieManager = new CookieManager();

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PostData);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    new loginTask().execute(getLoginData());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



 public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String loginData = params[0];
            String text = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Send data
            try {
                // Defined URL  where to send data
                URL login_url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);

                // getting cookies:
                URLConnection conn = login_url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();

                // setting cookies
                cookieManager.storeCookies(conn);
                cookieManager.setCookies(login_url.openConnection());

                cookiestring = cookieManager.toString();

                Log.d("Cookie in logintask:", cookiestring);

                conn.getContent();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                try {
                    wr.write(loginData); //post
                    wr.flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Get the server response
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.length() > 0) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        if (line == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                text = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (reader != null) reader.close();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return text;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
            if (!line.contains("I107")) { //I107 is an error code that is returend when a login failed
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }
    }


public void setCookies(URLConnection conn) throws IOException {

    // let's determine the domain and path to retrieve the appropriate cookies
    URL url = conn.getURL();
    String domain = getDomainFromHost(url.getHost());
    String path = url.getPath();

    Map domainStore = (Map)store.get(domain);
    if (domainStore == null) return;
    StringBuffer cookieStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    Iterator cookieNames = domainStore.keySet().iterator();
    while(cookieNames.hasNext()) {
        String cookieName = (String)cookieNames.next();
        Map cookie = (Map)domainStore.get(cookieName);
        // check cookie to ensure path matches  and cookie is not expired
        // if all is cool, add cookie to header string
        if (comparePaths((String)cookie.get(PATH), path) && isNotExpired((String)cookie.get(EXPIRES))) {
            cookieStringBuffer.append(cookieName);
            cookieStringBuffer.append("=");
            cookieStringBuffer.append((String)cookie.get(cookieName));
            if (cookieNames.hasNext()) cookieStringBuffer.append(SET_COOKIE_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }
    try {
        conn.setRequestProperty(COOKIE, cookieStringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ise) {
        IOException ioe = new IOException("Illegal State! Cookies cannot be set on a URLConnection that is already connected. "
                + "Only call setCookies(java.net.URLConnection) AFTER calling java.net.URLConnection.connect().");
        throw ioe;
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you set the login cookie?

Comment: i have added the setcookies method at the bottom

Comment: Buddy I have had a very bitter experience in setting cookies using URL connection and then carrying them forward as session cookies for the webview. The reverse however worked flawless for me.